# Is there any representation for kth branch of Lambert-$W$ function?

Tags: lambert-w

How to represent the infinite branches of Lambert$W$ function? I just tried to solve it graphically in mathematica and got an interesting representation of the function,  which is helpful in understanding this function. Please check my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mathematics, the Lambert-W function, also called the omega function or product logarithm, is a set of functions, namely the branches of the inverse relation of the function $f(z) = ze^{z}$ where $e^{z}$ is the exponential function and z is any complex number. In other words $$z=f^{-1}(ze^{z})=W(ze^{z})$$
Now, Taking equation $ze^{z}=c$, $c\in R$. This imply $z=W_{k}(c)$.  where $W_{k}$ for k an integer are countably many branches of the W function. $W_{0}$ being the principal branch.  $W_{0}(x)$ is real and positive for $x \in (0,\infty)$ and $W_{0}(x)$,$W_{-1}(x)$ both are real and negative for  $x \in (\frac{-1}{e},0)$. and all other $W_{k}(x)$ are complex $\forall x$.[image]

Subsituting, $z=x+iy$, and seperating real and imaginary parts we get $$e^{x}(x\cos{y}-y\sin{y})=c~~\&~~ie^{x}(x\sin{y}+y\cos{y})=0.$$
After further simplification we get $$x=-y\cot{y}~~\&~~x=\log{-\frac{c\sin{y}}{y}}$$
[image]

I calculated the point of intersection of this graph for $c=1$. To find out y cordinate of point of intersection.
 $$FindRoot[- y*\cot[y] - Log[-1*\sin[y]/y], (y, \frac{3\pi}{2})]$$ this command gives root near $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ as it is can be seen in graph that we have root near $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ and the output is $(y \rightarrow4.37519)$. putting this output in $-y\cot[y]$ we get $x \rightarrow -1.53391$, Thus, (-1.53391,4.37519) will satisfy $ (x+iy )*e^{-(x+iy)} = 1.$
 And from the symmetry of graph (-1.53391,-4.37519) is also a solution.

Input -  $$Table[ ProductLog[k, 1], {k, -2, 2}] // N$$
  Output-  $$ {-2.401 - 10.77 I, -1.533 - 4.375 I, 0.5671, -1.533 + 
    4.375 I, -2.401 + 10.776 I}   $$ 
 Now, we can see the point of intersection exatly matches with Lambert W function. These are the values of  $W_{k}(1)$ from $k=-2~to~2$. From here we can atempt to write general expression of $W_{k}$.
  $$Im(W_{k}(c))=y:-y\cot{y}=\log{-\frac{c\sin{y}}{y}}, \begin{cases}{}
     2k\pi <y<(2k+1)\pi~~for~~k\geq0 \\
   (2k+1)\pi <y<(2k+2)\pi~~for~~k<0\\
    \end{cases} $$
   $$Re(W_{k}(c))= -y\cot{y}~or~\log{-\frac{c\sin{y}}{y}}: y ~is ~the~ Im(W_{k}(c))$$
    This expression is true for $c<\frac{-1}{e}$ where all roots are imaginary. For $\frac{-1}{e}<c<0$ this expression is still true except for real roots $W_{-1}$ and $W_{0}$.

For $c>0$ only $W_{0}$ is real, thus expression is:
      $$Im(W_{k}(c))=y:-y\cot{y}=\log{-\frac{c\sin{y}}{y}}, \begin{cases}{}
     (2k-1)\pi <y<2k\pi~~for~~k>0 \\
   (2k)\pi <y<(2k+1)\pi~~for~~k<0\\
    \end{cases} $$
       $$Re(W_{k}(c))= -y\cot{y}~or~\log{-\frac{c\sin{y}}{y}}: y ~is ~the~ Im(W_{k}(c))$$